# What is the best material to make a fake muffin from?

Tags: material-selection

I want to make a realistic looking muffin but I am uncertain what materials to use. Other than clay or plaster, what solutions are there?

Is there something that I could literally bake like a real muffin, that won't go off?

Comment: I feel like there ought to be something based on baking soda and glue, plaster or similar, but I'm not finding it

Answer (score 5):

- You can use expansion foam and colour it afterwards with spray paints, as is suggested [here](https://www.instructables.com/Fake-Cupcakes/). But that's a lot of unnecessary (toxic) waste, and, besides, you can't bake it.
- So I suggest basing your method on [this recipe for fake bread](https://www.ehow.com/how_6522400_make-fake-bread.html), which allows you to use ingredients very similar to the ones you'd use when making real bread:

  > Mix 4 cups of flour, 1 cup of salt and 2 cups of water in a mixing bowl.

  This dough is for white bread. You can use food colouring to colour your muffins (e.g. brown for 'chocolate muffins').
  Knead this dough well, and put it into muffin tins, cupcake trays or liners, or even just mugs.

  > Bake the fake bread until it browns in an oven set at 300 degrees Fahrenheit [150 °C]. Check it at 20 minutes. Adjust the time and temperature for your oven, if necessary.

  This is for a loaf, so I suggest checking it earlier than 20 minutes (and let me know what time works best if you try this method out :).

  > Brush craft glue over the top of the fake bread to simulate the shine from egg white on real bread, if desired. Sprinkle the top with [..] decoration [if desired].

Good luck!

Comment: That salt dough is more like fake biscuits than fake bread, but would still work well here. Shaping it might be interesting as it doesn't rise. If you want it to last, you'll need to give it a few coats of varnish otherwise it absorbs moisture from the air and eventually falls apart.

Comment: I guess you could add a pinch of baking powder to salt dough. However, I would stuff a ball of aluminum foil in the center of this muffin because salt dough is prone to cracking in such thick objects. The foil decreases the weight of the finished object, the risk of cracking and the baking time. Keep the bottom layer thick and form the crown of the muffin around some aluminum foil to keep the center of gravity low and avoid your muffin falling over at the slightest nudge.